# Salesforce SLDS dyanmically populate dropdown

Tags: slds

I have a dropdown which I have to populate from the custom setting values. I have to use SLDS system and not standard salesforce. Can someone tell me how to go about this? I just want to know how I should proceed for making a dropdown list using SLDS as I am very new to it. 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

SLDS stands for "Salesforce Lightning *Design* System" (emphasis is mine) and it is not a programming language, you can't populate and manipulate data with it. Depending on what you want to do (Lightning Component, VF Page) and how you want to do it (on the client, on the server) you need to use either Apex/VF or Javascript.